# Edit context menu (selectiontree) in customize dialog?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

How do I edit the context menu (selectiontree) in a customize dialog?

I don't want to display the option "entire feature will be installed on local hard drive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove this option. It gets displayed when your feature has subfeatures and allows selecting all subfeatures for installation as well as the currently selected (parent) feature, without clicking each of child features.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12987421/572834) to [How to hide feature options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12938627/572834).